# Using Meteor Spotify API to return list of albums based on word search and need to pull in tracks for each album in the list

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, meteor

I am using a spotify web api wrapper package called [xinranxiao:spotify-web-api](https://atmospherejs.com/xinranxiao/spotify-web-api). I am able to return a list of albums based on textual input, using methods and calls on the server and client.

I am trying to use two methods, one for the search itself, and the other to tie in the album tracks with each search result. The issue for me is the JSON results are separate, and I need to get an array for IDs from the the album search and pass them through the second method. I am not sure how to extract the array, not even sure if I am going in the right direction. Here is my code so far. The code below actually works, except that it is obviously brings the same tracks in for all returned albums. I suspect most of my issue is a lack of knowledge in parsing json. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

--On Server

```js
Meteor.methods({

  searchAlbums: function(query) {
    var spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi();
    //grab JSON list of albums based on text search
    var response = spotifyApi.searchAlbums(query, {
      limit: 50
    });
    // Need to refresh token
    if (checkTokenRefreshed(response, spotifyApi)) {
      response = spotifyApi.searchAlbums(query, {
        limit: 50
      });
    }
    return response.data.body;
  },

  fetchTracks: function(id) {
    var spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi();
    //grab JSON list of tracks based on album id
    var response = spotifyApi.getAlbum(id);
    // Need to refresh token
    if (checkTokenRefreshed(response, spotifyApi)) {
      response = spotifyApi.getAlbum(id);
    }
    return response.data.body;
  }

});

var checkTokenRefreshed = function(response, api) {
  if (response.error && response.error.statusCode === 401) {
    api.refreshAndUpdateAccessToken();
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};
```

--On Client

```js
Template.spotify.events({
  'click .submit': function(e, template) {

    var albumName = $('.albumName').val();
    //temporary to get key/values from JSON
    var albumId = '4v7ImrdxXL4rYPutcdmyXV';

    Meteor.call('searchAlbums', albumName, function(err, response) {
      Session.set('album', response.albums.items);
        console.log(response);

    });

    Meteor.call('fetchTracks', albumId, function(err, response) {
      Session.set('albumTracks', response.tracks.items);
      console.log(response);
    });

  }
});
```

--Template

```html
<template name="spotify">
  {{> loginButtons}}
  <h3>Search for albums with a specified word</h3>
  <div class="track__search">
    <input class="albumName" data-source="searchAlbums" name="search" placeholder="Search albums" tabindex="1" type="text" />
    <input class="submit" name="submit" type="submit" />
  </div>
  <div class="track__results">
    {{# each $.Session.get 'album' }}
    <div class="track">
      <div class="thumb">
        <img src="{{ images.[0].url }}" />
      </div>
      <div class="name">
        <strong>Album Name:</strong>
        <a href="{{ external_urls.spotify }}" target="_blank">{{ name }}</a>
        <div class="albumId" data-album-id="{{ id }}">{{ id }}</div>
        <br/>
        <strong>AlbumTracks:</strong>
        <ol>
          {{# each $.Session.get 'albumTracks' }}
          <li>
            {{ name }}
          </li>
          {{/each}}
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: This question isn't specific to Meteor. You can put a javascript and ajax tag in as well since a large part of this has to deal with coding strategy and good ways to manipulate objects.

Comment: What are you trying to ask?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a call of the *fetchTracks* method after the response of the *searchAlbums* method.

On client.

```
    var albumId = '';

    Meteor.call('searchAlbums', albumName, function(err, response) {
      if(response){
        Session.set('album', response.albums.items);
        //You will need to update this to get all the albums tracks
        albumId = response.albums.items[0].id;

        Meteor.call('fetchTracks', albumId, function(err, response) {
          Session.set('albumTracks', response.tracks.items);
          console.log(response.tracks.items);
        });
      }

    });
```